# I'm having some trouble with li::before content and the bullet unicode

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of a list bullet, i followed some tutorials and it's working fine, except that when i type the unicode "\2022" and refresh the page, the "\" is gone and the website displays something like:

2 
0 
2 
2 "li text"

```
.li-especialidades::before {
    content: "\2022"; /* when i load the page \ is gone */
    color: #e5cf00;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

ps: it's a wordpress website

Comment: Hey Gabriel. I'm unable to replicate the issue given your provided code. Can you please elaborate or provide some more information regarding the context of your environment?

Comment: <ul class="ul-especialidades">
  <li class="li-especialidades white">text</li>
  <li class="li-especialidades white">text</li>
  <li class="li-especialidades white">text</li>
</ul>

.ul-especialidades {
    list-style: none;
}

forgot to say that it's a wordpress website

Comment: There are other combos you can use for this character https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm

Comment: Try a double backslash: `content: "\\2022";`

Comment: Unless there's something more specific to this, why not just do like `.li-especialidades { list-style-type: disc; }` and [move on](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_all) with your day? Provided that the context is semantically correct in that the parent is `display: list` and the children are `display: list-item`.

Comment: No success with the other combos or the double backslash

Comment: Because I need to change it's color, and I'm following orders, so it needs to be that color @ChrisW.

Comment: Then what you have already should work fine. Did you by chance forget to reset the parent style via like `ul { list-style: none; }` ?

Comment: Nope, it's styled this way

Comment: You'll probably need to go ahead and supply some more info then because currently can't reproduce the issue just following [basic common method](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp) you're showing here.

Answer (score 0):

I lack some reputation to comment. But your code should actually work. Did some research and I found [some way](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html) to achieve the result you want. Hope this will help.

```
.li-especialidades::before {
    content: "•"; /* I copied the disk itself */
    color: #e5cf00;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```